# Rename existing Sencha touch project

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have an existing Sencha touch project and I use Sencha architect as IDE. Now I would like to rename the project. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you tried changing name in app.js ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Project Inspector for Sencha Architect 3 you can click on "Application" and find a property there called `name` which you can edit.

Comment: If tried this already, unfortunatly afterwards my app is not shown anymore and I get no errors just the blue sencha screen with the blinking dots.

Comment: @stefan what does the name in the app.json file say after the change in architect?